# How to use dynamic value of @PreAuthorize with @ExceptionHandler in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, exceptionhandler

We are using **@PreAuthorize** with **dynamic value**. and at the request model we used bean validation means @NotEmpty,...

**Code of controller:**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/../{id}/...")
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority(#id+'abc')")
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    SerivceAbc service;

    @PostMapping("/test")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> validate(@PathVariable String id,
            @Valid @RequestBody RequestModel Request,
            ContentCachingRequestWrapper requestWrapper) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(service.abc(Request, requestWrapper));
    }

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ExceptionHandler( MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    ResponseEntity<Object> handleValidationExceptions(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex,
            ContentCachingRequestWrapper requestWrapper) {
        ResponseModel invalidResponse = service.invalidResponse(ex,
                requestWrapper);
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(invalidResponse);
    }

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    ResponseEntity<Object> handleValidationExceptions(Exception ex, ContentCachingRequestWrapper requestWrapper) {
        ResponseModel invalidResponse = service.invalidResponse(ex,
                requestWrapper);
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(invalidDssReponse);
    }
}
```

In the above code `id` is a dynamic value that is working fine when we call `\test` API with passing valid fields

but whenever any bean validation is called at that time it's not calling `handleValidationExceptions` method because of **dynamic id**.

if I'm trying to pass id as a parameter of `handleValidationExceptions` method I'm getting error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not resolve parameter [2] in org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.Object> com.controller.TestController.handleValidationExceptions(org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException,org.springframework.web.util.ContentCachingRequestWrapper,java.lang.String): No suitable resolver

Can anyone please suggest how can we use @PreAuthorize (dynamic value)  with exceptionhandler?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access `@PathVariable` in the exception handler, you can simply register its `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` in the `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver` :

```java
@Configuration
public class Config implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void extendHandlerExceptionResolvers(List<HandlerExceptionResolver> resolvers) {

        for(HandlerExceptionResolver resolver : resolvers){
            if(resolver instanceof ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver e){
                e.getArgumentResolvers().addResolver(new PathVariableMethodArgumentResolver());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then change the `@ExceptionHandler` to :

```java
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
@ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
ResponseEntity<Object> handleValidationExceptions(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, @PathVariable String id) {
   
}
```